# Handlebars.compile is not a function

Tags: meteor, handlebars.js

Has anyone had this issue with handlebars & meteor?

Uncaught TypeError: Handlebars.compile is not a function

I have added the handlebars package.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

The handlebars package is deprecated, recommended is spacebars

https://atmospherejs.com/meteor/spacebars

I think it might work better

Comment: Hi Mikkel, I have implemented space bars but get another issue now.

Comment: 'Uncaught TypeError: template is not a function'

Comment: it's specifically referring to this function which use to work with handlebars 'function showTemplate(template, data){
 var html    = template(data);
 $('#content').html(html);
}